# Django ignore 500 errors

Tags: django, twilio

I have developed an ecommerce store in Django where I am using twilio sms functionality. Using twilio, sms only sends if number is in proper format and valid.

```
message = client.messages.create(
body="Dear customer, this is sample msg", to= number, from_= contact )
```

So I want a way through which if twilio raise an error in sending sms, this errors gets ignore [Don't raise Server Error 500 in prod]. And Website functionality remains normal.

Is there any way to cater it?

Comment: In ```settings.py``` file, do ```DEBUG = True``` then find out the problem line number and cause

Comment: If you are using twilio API functionality it will probably return some error code if the number is not in the right format. You should catch that error and create message for user accordingly. This should be done in production to stay away from 500 errors

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic can you show some sample code for that?

Comment: @MdJeweleIslam It happens when number is not correct

Answer (score 0):

To cater such situation, this simply worked:

```
try:    
     message = client.messages.create(
     body="Dear customer, this is sample msg", to= number, from_= contact )
except Exception as e:
     pass
```

Comment: This code just ignores whatever status is returned from provider. If that was what you were looking for, it will work. I prefer to handle more gracefully errors and present something to user. I really don't know what you get back from provider, but I presume that some error or OK code is given back.